# How to orbit the scene using three.js?

Tags: three.js, 3d

Hey guys I am using `three.js` and have tried to rotate this plane below but to avail. Any idea how to do it please? Below is the code which renders the plane using `three.js`. How can I rotate it, please?. Thanks!

```js
 var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var plane;

var mouse, raycaster, isShiftDown = false;

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff80, overdraw: 0.5 } );

var objects = [];

init();
render();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
    info.style.position = 'absolute';
    info.style.top = '10px';
    info.style.width = '100%';
    info.style.textAlign = 'center';
    info.innerHTML = '<a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - voxel painter<br><strong>click</strong>: add voxel, <strong>shift + click</strong>: remove voxel, <a href="javascript:save()">save .png</a>';
    container.appendChild( info );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 500, 800, 1300 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

    // Grid

    var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 1000, 20 );
    scene.add( gridHelper );

    //

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    //PlaneBufferGeometry: platform to lay cubes
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10000, 10000 );
    geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

    plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { visible: false } ) );
    scene.add( plane );

    objects.push( plane );

    // Lights

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x606060 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x808080 );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    //document.addEventListener( 'keydown', onDocumentKeyDown, false );
    //document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUp, false );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    render();

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

        if ( isShiftDown ) {

            if ( intersect.object != plane ) {

                scene.remove( intersect.object );

                objects.splice( objects.indexOf( intersect.object ), 1 );

            }

        } else {

            var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
            voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
            voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
            scene.add( voxel );

            objects.push( voxel );

        }

        render();

    }

}

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
```

Look at the Plane here
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use [`THREE.OrbitControls`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls).

Add orbit control:

```
orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
```

And animate your scene continuously:

```
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Further you have to manage how `THREE.OrbitControls` and the mouse event (`onDocumentMouseDown`) interact together.

A possibility would be to handle only the left mouse button in `onDocumentMouseDown`:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    if ( event.button != 0 ) // 0 means left mouse button
        return;
```

And to rotate the scene by the right mouse button. This can be done by setting the [`.mouseButtons`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/controls/OrbitControls.mouseButtons) property of `OrbitControls`:

```
orbitControls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT
}
```

Further note, that you can enable or disable pane, zoom and rotate by setting `.enablePan`, `.enableZoom` respectively `.enableRotate`.

See the following example, where the boxes are positioned by the left mouse button and the scene can be rotated by holding the right mouse button:

```js
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var plane;

var mouse, raycaster, isShiftDown = false;

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff80, overdraw: 0.5 } );

var objects = [];

init();
render();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.set( 500, 800, 1300 );
    camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xf0f0f0 );

    var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 1000, 20 );
    scene.add( gridHelper );

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    //PlaneBufferGeometry: platform to lay cubes
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 10000, 10000 );
    geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

    plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { visible: false } ) );
    scene.add( plane );

    objects.push( plane );

    // Lights

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x606060 );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0x808080 );
    directionalLight.position.x = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.y = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.z = Math.random() - 0.5;
    directionalLight.position.normalize();
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    orbitControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera); 
    orbitControls.mouseButtons = {
     LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT,
     MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE,
     RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT
    }

    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
   
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

    if ( event.button != 0 )
       return;

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

        if ( isShiftDown ) {

            if ( intersect.object != plane ) {

                scene.remove( intersect.object );

                objects.splice( objects.indexOf( intersect.object ), 1 );

            }

        } else {

            var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
            voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
            voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
            scene.add( voxel );

            objects.push( voxel );

        }
    }
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```